# What are the different types of heaps that exist on Android and what is their significance?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-memory

I'm aware of the java heap and dalvik heap, and today I was introduced to ashmem. Do others exists? What's the significance of these different regions of memory and what does android use each one for?